# Ruby method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I wrote a simple product class and instantiated from the class.

```
#This class defines a product
#It provides a method that can be used to provide a discount on any given instance of a product

class Product
  attr_reader :name, :description, :price

  def initialize (name, description, price)
    @name = name
    @description = description
    @price = Float(price)
  end

  def price=(sale_price)
    @price = sale_price
  end

  def to_s
    "Name: #{@name}, Description: #{@description}, Price: #{@price}."
  end
end 

my_product = Product.new("redshoes","These are beautiful",50.00)
my_product.price = my_product.price * 0.50
puts "The new sale price of #{my_product.name} is #{my_product.price}"
```

I have one problem I need clarification on and that is when i define a method like this :

```
def price=(sale_price)
  @price = sale_price
end
```

I'm defining the method and assigning it to a variable at the same time . The first line  "def price=(sale_price)" is a bit confusing since I wrote it based on research online and books but  if I can get a bit of clarification on this it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys. @@ Guilherme Bernal I made a change to my code since you mentioned that the two methods are the same however I get error wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
 def price(sale_price)
    @price = sale_price 
  end
  def to_s 
    "Name: #{@name}, Description: #{@description}, Price: #{@price}."
  end
end

my_product = Product.new("redshoes","These are beautiful",50.00)
my_product.price = my_product.price * 0.50
puts "The new sale price of #{my_product.name} is #{my_product.price}"

Answer (score 1):

This is just the method name.

```
def set_price(p)
  @price = p
end
```

or:

```
def price=(p)
  @price = p
end
```

And you call this way:

```
product.set_price(100)
product.price=(100)
```

See? No change. The magic shows up when Ruby allows you to omit the parens and add spaces between the equal and the rest of the name:

```
product.price = 100
```

This is just an usual method call. Nothing fancy going on.

Comment: Nit-pick: This explanation isn't entirely accurate. Ruby doesn't just allow you to omit parens and add spaces around the equals sign in a setter method name — the setter syntax is a special construct that calls the underlying setter method, but is not the same as calling it directly. For example, let's say that our setter is instead `def price=(p) @price = p; 42 end`. If writing `product.price = 100` were equivalent to `product.send(:price=, 100)`, we'd expect both calls to return 42, but instead `product.price = 100` returns 100 while `product.send(:price=, 100)` returns 42.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will make more sense if you understand what `def` is actually doing. In your example of `def price=(sale_price)`, "price=" is the name of the method you're defining on the Product class. When you call `my_product.price =`, you're calling the method you defined called "price=".

You don't actually change any value until you set the instance variable `@price` equal to the input of your method (the variable `sale_price`).

The reason `my_product.price` (without the equal sign) works is because you've defined an attribute called `:price` using `attr_reader :price`, which is a helpful way of giving you read access to the instance variable `@price`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's how ruby does setter methods.  Keep in mind there's no requirement that the method name and the variable name match, nor for that any assignment actually takes place, though that's probably good practice most of the time.

but you could have:

```
def confuse=(ignore_me)
    puts "Silly human, #{ignore_me} is being ignored!"
end
```

which would be invoked any time you have

```
object.confuse = something
```

and not perform any actual assignment.